# Script does not run under cron but runs manually again

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I am very sorry for asking this again, but I've tried all advices. I have 2 scripts in `/var/TPbackup_script/`. This is the first one:

```
mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD teampass > /var/TPbackups/TPbackup_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").sql
```

Corresponding cronjob in `/etc/crontab`

```
20 9    * * *   root    sudo sh /var/TPbackup_script/TPbackup_script
```

This script works in crontab. All is good. The second script does not run:

```
s3cmd sync /var/TPbackups s3://PwdMgmt
```

Corresponding cronjob in `/etc/crontab`:

```
25 9   * * *   root    sudo sh /var/TPbackup_script/TPsyncS3_script
```

This one fails. If i run it manually in terminal:

```
sudo sh /var/TPbackup_script/TPsyncS3_script
```

then it works perfectly. What i tried:

1) Trying to add shebang #!/bin/sh to the beginning of the script
2) Renaming script to TPsyncS3_script.sh
3) I have added script into cron.daily and it was in the list of daily cron tasks (i see it with command `run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily`)
No success.
Here is my /etc/crontab file:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
16 9    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
20 9    * * *   root    sudo sh /var/TPbackup_script/TPbackup_script
25 9    * * *   root    sudo sh /var/TPbackup_script/TPsyncS3_script.sh > /var/TPbackup_script/sync_log.txt
#
```

All permissions on scripts were set with `sudo chmod 777`.
And by the way. sync_log.txt was created after cronjob, but it's empty.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you checked your log files? What does `fgrep cron /var/log | fgrep TPsyncS3` say? Also, you don't really need the `sudo` part, since you're already setting up your cronjobs to run as `root`

Comment: where is "s3cmd"? is it in /bin or /usr/bin? Cron has a very restricted PATH. Does it rely on variables found in your environment?

Comment: Glenn, s3cmd is in /usr/bin. But i cant understand why it doesn't work, because i have /usr/bin path in my /etc/crontab file (you can see PATH in the main message).

Comment: And lanzz, i don't have any logs connected with s3cmd, or with TPsyncS3 in /var/log. And nothing happened when i entered commands from your answer.

Comment: Upd: I have added PATH parameter in the script with all s3cmd locations that i have found with whereis s3cmd. Now my script looking like this:`#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin/s3cmd:/usr/bin/X11/s3cmd:/usr/share/s3cmd:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
s3cmd sync /var/TPbackups s3://PwdMgmt` but still it's working if run it manually, but does not work in cron.

Comment: Does `root` have the necessary credentials for connecting to S3? If not, that's the problem. If yes, why? In other words, you should rethink your design rather than fix the immediate problem (if this is indeed where it lies).

Comment: Don't use 777 permission; use 755 permission.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Solved this by adding the option to specify the location of the s3cfg:

```
--config /root/.s3cfg
```

e.g:

```
s3cmd sync --config /root/.s3cfg /var/TPbackups s3://PwdMgmt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try to run your script using root's crontab.
do:
sudo crontab -e

Add your script and try again. It worked for me :)